# Integrate git and jenkins for merge sanity

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-pipelines

We are migrating to bitbucket from svn - our builds being executed by Jenkins.
For our code release cycle - we have adopted the git workflow https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
As part of the code sanity,we wish a pull request from a FEATURE branch to be allowed to merge into DEVELOP when and only if it has undergone a successful build.
What are the specific integration steps between git and jenkins that need to be put in place to enable this hook on pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple approaches for this. One in my opinion is to

1. Create `Multibranch Pipeline` and used [bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin#readme). Set trigger to poll SCM (or setup Bitbucket web hook for triggering job)
2. Configure `Branch permission` in bitbucket. Restrict direct commits on protected branches and set [`Check for {#} passed builds on the last commit`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/suggest-or-require-checks-before-a-merge-856691474.html) for pull request to be able to merge

`bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin` will take post build status on respective pull request.